# how to reuse modalpop up body multiple times in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, modal, popup-window

i have came across an issue of modalpop up in lwc where in we have "headers","Body" and "Footers"
 Now my issue is i am calling one LWC(Comp-1) component into my modal popup(LWC) on click of some hyperlink 
 The response is coming from lwc(Comp1) but when the data comes it is replicating the entire modalPop up(headers,body,footer) instead of reflecting only in body, so now we have 2 modal popups after response, below is the code.

```html
<div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1">
    <template if:true={firstLoad}>
        <p>The is Test information.</p> <br>
        <div align="center">Would you like to take 10 minutes to participate? </div> <br>
        <!--Opens get Started -->    
        <a href="#" onclick={handleClick}> Yes</a> <br>
    </template> 
    <template if:true={getStartedValue}>
        <c-get-started-model></c-get-started-model>
    </template>
</div>
```

Below is the JS code

```javascript
handleClick(evt) {
    const modal = this.template.querySelector("c-get-Started");
    modal.show();
}
```

Comment: i think you are trying to load modal inside the modal , can you add 'c-get-started-model'

Comment: @sdandamud1 c-get-started-model is not a modal up its just a html table which fetches the data.

Comment: can you add image, if you are not add complete code it's hard to give correct solution.